# How to bind adapter list item view with boolean in service

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I have a recyclerAdapter with multiple view types, in one row I have a button which starts a service and I replace the button by a spinning wheel when the service starts. The service sends a broadcast when it starts and stops so I can update the list row. Is there a way to use architecture components to solve this in a better way? Could I have a field in my ViewModel that is observed by the ViewHolder in some way and the service updates this field in the model instead of sending broadcasts?